# HTML5 Canvas blinking on drawing

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, refresh, blink

I'm beginning with an isometric game, and my canvas is blinking(Not in IE) when draws all the parts of the ground. When I set fps to 20 or less, the blinking stops. How can I solve that? Any ideas?

```
var camerax = 300, cameray = 100;
var fps = 60;

function draw() {
    clearCanvas();
    drawGround();
}

function drawGround() {
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function() {
    var width = img.width;
    var height = img.height;
    for (var x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
        for (var y = 3; y >= 0; y--) {
                mx = (x-y)*height + camerax;
                my = (x+y)*height/2 + cameray; 
                ctx.drawImage(img, mx, my);
             }
        }
    }
    img.src = "ground.png";
}

var loop = setInterval(function() {
    update();
    draw();
}, 1000/fps);
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Right now you're reloading the image every frame and unless the `onload` callback fires within the 16ms of the frame you're going to see a blank canvas.

You should only need to call the `new Image`, `img.onload` sequence once, to preload your images. The `onload` callback would then kick off your first frame, and the draw calls are free to use the image in memory.

Something like:

```
var camerax = 300, cameray = 100;
var fps = 60;
var img;
var loop;

function init() {
    img = new Image();
    img.onload = function() {
        loop = setInterval(function() {
            update();
            draw();
        }, 1000/fps);
    };
    img.src = "ground.png";
}

function draw() {
    clearCanvas();
    drawGround();
}

function drawGround() {
    var width = img.width;
    var height = img.height;
    for (var x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
        for (var y = 3; y >= 0; y--) {
                mx = (x-y)*height + camerax;
                my = (x+y)*height/2 + cameray; 
                ctx.drawImage(img, mx, my);
             }
        }
    }
}
```

Of course, it gets more complex once you're waiting for multiple images to preload since you need to start the loop only once all of them are done.

Answer (score 1):

Nice tip, freejosh! Thanks! My screen now is not blinking and the code result was that:

```
        var canvas = document.getElementById("game");
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

        var camerax = 300, cameray = 100;
        var fps = 60;
        var img;
        var loop;

        function update() {
        }

        function draw() {
            clearCanvas();
            drawGround();
        }

        function clearCanvas() {
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        }

        function drawGround() {
            var width = img.width;
            var height = img.height;
            for (var x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
                for (var y = 3; y >= 0; y--) {
                    mx = (x-y)*height + camerax;
                    my = (x+y)*height/2 + cameray; 
                    ctx.drawImage(img, mx, my);
                }
            }
        }

        function init() {
            img = new Image();
            img.onload = function() {
                drawGround();
            };
            img.src = "ground.png";
        }

        function keyListener(e){
           e = e || window.event

           if(e.keyCode==37){
              camerax--;
           }
           else if(e.keyCode==39){
              camerax++;
           }
           else if(e.keyCode==38){
              cameray--;
           }
           else if(e.keyCode==40){
              cameray++;
           }                           
        }

        window.onkeypress = function(e) {
            keyListener(e);
        }

        init();
        var loop = setInterval(function() {
            update();
            draw();
        }, 1000/fps);
```